# Catering for various android screen sizes or Developing universal screen layout?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app and I have to cater for pretty much majority of android devices between 4 inches and 10 inches and was wondering if there's a way to create a universal screen layout that would scale based on the device.

This would be a better way as opposed to my current logic of developing different layouts and respective activities for each screen category i.e. 4 inches, 5 inches etc.

As indicated below, I utilise the DisplayMetrics Fields and pythagoras theorem to determine the screen size i.e. for example to find the height of the device I undertake the following calculation:

```
double yDeviceScreenSize = Math.pow(DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels/DeviceScreenSize.ydpi,2);
```

The above line of code is essentially the absolute height of the display in pixels divided by the exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the Y dimension, followed by squaring the value.

In similar fashion I obtain the width figure the same way. This is indicated below:

```
double xDeviceScreenSize = Math.pow(DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels/DeviceScreenSize.xdpi,2);
```

The above calculations are followed by obtaining the square root value as indicated below, which I then utilise to pick a which I developed and tested on a device of the same screen size value:

```
DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen = Math.sqrt(xDeviceScreenSize + yDeviceScreenSize);
```

As indicated below, using the

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Below is my code screen determining method which I call in the on create of my splashscreen:

```
   // Splash screen delay
public final void SplashScreenThread() {

    //  For tracking purposes record in logcat SplashScreenThread() method has been called
    Log.i(TAG + "onCreate()", "SplashScreenThread(); HAS STARTED");

    // Thread for the display of the SplashScreen
    SightsandSoundsSplashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(active && (waited < SplashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {

                // do nothing
                Log.e(TAG + "SplashScreenThread()", "SplashScreenThread() ERROR IS AS FOLLOWS: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                    // Call method finish to kill any 
                    finish();

                    // Fetch the screen size in order to call correct layout wrt the next screen - firstly create and object of type DisplayMetrics
                    DisplayMetrics DeviceScreenSize = new DisplayMetrics();

                    // Secondly fetch the window manager using method chaining
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(DeviceScreenSize);

                    // Calculate the width of the screen in inches
                    double xDeviceScreenSize = Math.pow(DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels/DeviceScreenSize.xdpi,2);

                    // Record in logcat DeviceScreenSize.xdpi
                    Log.d(TAG,"DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels + " and DeviceScreenSize.xdpi is: " + DeviceScreenSize.xdpi);
                    Log.d(TAG,"DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels + " and DeviceScreenSize.ydpi is: " + DeviceScreenSize.ydpi);

                    // Calculate the height of the screen in inches
                    double yDeviceScreenSize = Math.pow(DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels/DeviceScreenSize.ydpi,2);

                    // Obtain screen size using pythagoras theorem
                    DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen = Math.sqrt(xDeviceScreenSize + yDeviceScreenSize);

                    // Record in logcat screen size in inches
                    Log.e(TAG,"DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels + "\nDeviceScreenSize.heightPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels + "\nScreen inches : " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);

                    // Identify device screen size based on calculation of screen size
                    if (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 2.9) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"< 2.9 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevltScn18inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - DEVICE DETERMINED TO BE LESS THAN 2.9 INCHES - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 2.9) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 3.6)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"2.9 to 3.6 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevltScn29inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);     

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);                               
                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 3.6) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 3.8)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"3.6 to 3.8 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevltScn29inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen); 

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 3.8) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 4.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"3.8 to 4.0 inch range called"); 

                           Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen38inches.class);
                           startActivity(loginscreen);
                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 4.0) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 4.28)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.0 to 4.28 inch range called");

                           Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen4inches.class);
                           startActivity(loginscreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    } else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 4.28) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 4.8)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.28 to 4.3 inch range called");

                           Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen428inches.class);
                           startActivity(loginscreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    } else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 4.8) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 4.9)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.8 to 4.9 inch range called");

                           Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen465inches.class);
                           startActivity(loginscreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 4.9) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 5.5)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.9 to 5.5 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen498inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);


                    } else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 5.5) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 5.9)) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"5.5 to 5.9 inch range called");

                            Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen57inches.class);
                            startActivity(loginscreen);

                            Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    } else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 5.9) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 6.8)) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"5.9 to 6.9 inch range called");

                            Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen59inches.class);
                            startActivity(loginscreen);

                       Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    } else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 6.8) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 7.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"6.0 to 7.0 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen699inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 7.0) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 8.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"7.0 to 8.0 inch range called");

                           Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen.class);
                           startActivity(loginscreen);

                    }  else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 8.0) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen < 9.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"8.0 to 9.0 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevltScnFinish.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    } else if ((DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen >= 9.0) && (DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen <= 10.2)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"> 9.0 to 10.2 inch range called");

                           Intent loginscreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen10inches.class);
                           startActivity(loginscreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + DeviceScreenSizeInInchesToDisplayLogInScreen);
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    SightsandSoundsSplashThread.start();
}
```

Below is my manifest indicating the position of my

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bge.applcs.dsa"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.07">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>


    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/iclauncher96"
        android:label="@string/appname"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />   

        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity   
            android:name="com.applcs.SplashScreenFour"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is an example of a layout I have created.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llbgedsafinccalclayout7inches"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/imgplainbackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rlbgedsafinccalclayout7inches"
        android:layout_width="925dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/imgbgedsafinccalcmainbitbgnd2">

     <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvcurrencysign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/> -->        

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ettotalvalue7inches"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="389dp"
        android:maxLength="9"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:background="#07000000"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btngenerate7inches"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ettotalvalue7inches"
        android:background="@drawable/btngeneratebgnd"/>    

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btntwoyears7inches"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ettotalvalue7inches"
        android:background="@drawable/btntwoyears"/>    

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btntthreeyears7inches"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ettotalvalue7inches"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btntwoyears7inches"
        android:background="@drawable/btnthreeyears"/>  

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnfouryears7inches"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ettotalvalue7inches"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btntthreeyears7inches"
        android:background="@drawable/btnfouryears"/>   

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnfiveyears7inches"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ettotalvalue7inches"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnfouryears7inches"
        android:background="@drawable/btnfiveyears"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvweeklypayment"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btntwoyears7inches"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>         

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvfirstpayment"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvweeklypayment"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvmonthlypayment"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvfirstpayment"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>        

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtotalcostpayment"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="351dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnfiveyears7inches"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvweeklypayment"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>        

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtaxreliefpayment"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="351dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtotalcostpayment"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvfirstpayment"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>        

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnetcostpayment"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="351dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtaxreliefpayment"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvmonthlypayment"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>       

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnumbofmonthlypayments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtaxreliefpayment"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:text="24"
        android:textColor="#FFD700"
        android:background="#07000000"/>         

    </RelativeLayout>   

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rlnotes7inches"
        android:layout_width="925dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/imgnotesbgnd"> 

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvinvalidentry7inches"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="370dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlbgedsafinccalclayout7inches"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:background="#07000000"/>  

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btninfo7inches"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlbgedsafinccalclayout7inches"
        android:background="@drawable/btninfobgnd"/>    

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvdateandtime7inches"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="515dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/rlbgedsafinccalclayout7inches"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btninfo7inches"
         android:background="#07000000"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textSize="25sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

     <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalclock7inches"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:background="#07000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlbgedsafinccalclayout7inches"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvdateandtime7inches"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)? There's lots of information there about how to deal with different screen sizes.

Typically it's just a case of creating several layouts. The exact number depends on how different you want your layouts to be between devices.

These layouts are placed in the `res/layout-*/` folders such as `res/layout-xhdpi/` or `res/layout-land/` or `res/layout-land-sw800dp/` (see the doc for details on what's supported)

The Android system will automatically select the appropriate layout depending on screen orientation, pixel density and size provided.

In the case of the layout you've provided, you're using many absolute measurements for widths/heights/margins, as is common with traditional desktop UI design. But, as you've discovered, on mobile devices this approach does not scale (pun not intended!) - every other type of screen/orientation will not fit these measurements. You have to change how you approach UI design.

In your case it looks like your layout represents a form that a user must fill in relating to a subscription that requires a regular weekly or monthly payment over a period of 2-5 year years. The elements have been laid out in both axis to make maximum use of the available screen estate, and this is causing further issues.

To start with, you could probably start by breaking your layout down into two tiles - on the left you have the 'generate' and 4x 'year' buttons, and on the right you have the initial/weekly/monthly payment summary. These could just be two `RelativeLayout` containers inside an outer `LinearLayout` set in horizontal orientation mode. (Then you can create a layout for portrait screens where the only difference is that the `LinearLayout` is set to vertical orientation, thereby making the two tiles display as a single vertical column).

For each of the two child layouts, make sure the buttons and labels are aligned relative to their parent. Avoid giving elements absolute widths or heights - only `WRAP_CONTENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` as far as you can. Same for margins - margins work best for creating small gaps between neighbouring elements and should only rarely be used for positioning items on a screen. Make sure you use DP dimensions for text sizes.

This use of relative positioning and measuring will help keep all your UI elements responsive to the screen they're being displayed on. Keep testing your UI on a couple of different screen sizes and orientations to keep a handle on how they look.

That should get you started. It's really a case of understanding how Android's various layouts have been designed let you work with multiple screens, and how absolute positioning is the devil!

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the reply. I've gone through the "Supporting Multiple Screens" document specifically in the density independence section of the document, it states that density independence can be achieved by specifying all layout dimension values in dp units or with wrap content. I have undertaken this and in addition provided alternative bitmap resources. I'm still baffled as to how and why I cant get one universal layout to work for all screen sizes?

Comment: If you could add one of your layouts to your question that would certainly help.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've added a layout I've created. It is for 7 inch devices but how can I use this layout or another layout as a single layout?